# When changing wallpaper black screen is displaying android

Tags: android, android-wallpaper

When I change the wallpaper, black screen is displaying before loading the new wallpaper.

How to remove the black screen in android.

When changing wallpaper -> **Blackscreen** -> New Wallpaper.

Where this blackscreen been implemented in android aosp?

Answer (score 0):

Changing wallpaper is a time taking task if you are simply using `WallpaperManager.setBitmap` for sure it will turn your screen first to black and than set new wallpaper.
If you want to keep using this try it running on background thread otherwise use

```
WallpaperService
```

Comment: Yes it uses wallpaperManager.setBitmap(blank). What if I comment this portion?    Bitmap blank = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
            // set a blank wallpaper to force a redraw of default_wallpaper
            wallpaperManager.setBitmap(blank);
            wallpaperManager.setResource(com.android.internal.R.drawable.default_wallpaper);

Comment: yes you can comment this but check the next line where it is setting new wallpaper. Providing new bitmap to be set as a wallpaper.

Comment: As per given information your code is actually setting a blank screen as  a wallpaper first than setting a new wallpaper so you can directly set a new wallpaper by commenting those lines